# Is there a way to fetch parent or sibling elements using client side js in lightning?

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I searched for a tutorial or refernce to all functions in client side js usage in lightning. Couldn't find any..

I need to find the closest **select** tag's value while i type anything in the input with class 'number_input' and vice versa.

```
<div class="slds-grid ">
        <div class="slds-col slds-size--6-of-12 slds-medium-size--8-of-12 slds-large-size--8-of-12 slds-text-heading--label">{!v.activityDetail.merchandize__Product_Name__c}</div>
        <div class="slds-col slds-size--3-of-12 slds-medium-size--2-of-12 slds-large-size--2-of-12">
            <div class="slds-form-element slds-float--right">
                <input type="number" min="0" id="{! 'price' + v.activityDetail.Id}" class="slds-input number_input" onkeyup="{!c.changePrice}"/>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="slds-col slds-size--3-of-12 slds-medium-size--2-of-12 slds-large-size--2-of-12">
            <div class="slds-form-element slds-float--right">
                <select id="{! 'unit' + v.activityDetail.Id}" class="slds-select select" onchange="{!c.changeUnit}" >
                                <option value="Bottle">Bottle</option>
                                <option value="Glass">Glass</option>
                                <option value="Shots">Shots</option>
                            </select>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Can anybody help me?